# Printing to stdout causes blocked goroutine to run?

Tags: concurrency, go, goroutine

As a silly basic threading exercise, I've been trying to implement the [sleeping barber problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_barber_problem) in golang. With channels this should be quite easy, but I've run into a heisenbug. That is, when I try to diagnose it, the problem disappears!

Consider the following. The `main()` function pushes integers (or "customers") onto the `shop` channel. `barber()` reads the `shop` channel to cut "customers'" hair. If I insert a `fmt.Print` statement into the `customer()` function, the program runs as expected. Otherwise, `barber()` never cuts anyone's hair.

```go
package main

import "fmt"

func customer(id int, shop chan<- int) {
    // Enter shop if seats available, otherwise leave
    // fmt.Println("Uncomment this line and the program works")
    if len(shop) < cap(shop) {
        shop <- id
    }
}

func barber(shop <-chan int) {
    // Cut hair of anyone who enters the shop
    for {
        fmt.Println("Barber cuts hair of customer", <-shop)
    }
}

func main() {
    shop := make(chan int, 5) // five seats available
    go barber(shop)
    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        customer(i, shop)
    }
}
```

Any idea what's afoot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the way Go's scheduler is implemented. The current goroutine can yield to other goroutines only when it makes a system call or a blocking channel operation. `fmt.Println` makes a system call, giving the goroutine an opportunity to yield. Otherwise it doesn't have one.

In practice this doesn't often matter, but for small problems like this it can sometimes crop up.

Also, a more idiomatic, less racy way of doing a non-blocking send on a channel is:

```
func customer(id int, shop chan<- int) {
    // Enter shop if seats available, otherwise leave
    select {
    case shop <- id:
    default:
    }
}
```

The way you're doing it, a customer could end up waiting outside of the barber shop since by the time you actually do the send, `len(shop)` may have changed.

Comment: Your answer holds if there is only one thread being used by the go runtime. Setting GOMAXPROCS either through runtime call like lazy1 says or setting the environment variable will also allow any goroutine to run parallel to other goroutines on a seperate thread. It might be worth expanding your answer to reflect how go's runtime multiplexes goroutines on the available threads.

Answer (score 1):

Does adding `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)` at the beginning of main solves this?

Comment: @MattJoiner Can you elaborate?

Comment: Increasing the level of parallelism only makes concurrency bugs less likely to crop up. They're still there. Correct code should work regardless of the the value of GOMAXPROCS. Perhaps watching Rob Pike's Concurrency is not Parallelism talk might make this clearer.